# Should i have webpack on production server?

Tags: webpack

I am using vue.js and webpack for my development. Lets say i want to upload my project to production server. As i can see, webpack is listed in my devdependencies. So this makes me believe that webpack shouldnt be installed on production at all.

**Question**: Should i have webpack installed on production server for bundling files or i should build it on my local computer and upload dist folder to production server directly?

couldn't find the proper answer. All other suggested answers say is that CI/CD tool is for that. My question is only about webpack. Should I have it at all installed on the production server ? if yes, then why is it in my devDependencies in my package.json?

What do you think? How do you do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Webpack: Should I build bundle on production server or build it locally and then upload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46117945/webpack-should-i-build-bundle-on-production-server-or-build-it-locally-and-then)

Comment: I dont think so. Answers are pretty bad for that question

Comment: The quality of the answers doesn't have anything to do with if the question is a duplicate or not. Set up a [bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) if you want better answers.

Comment: Well devDependencies do not go into production, they are for development only. That is why that is different. Webpack builds your application so if you are in production it probably should not change. So I would say no. I don't have experience in this. But I wanted to help a little more than JJJ did with his tone.